# Can't upload an android application in google play

Tags: android

After i finished "export signed application package" for my android application, i want to upload my last version application to google play.

I get error message like this :

> **Upload failed**
>
> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs.
> You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) > with fingerprint(s):
>
> SHA1: FC:DA:7B:3C:33:A2:87:41:D6:25:8C:FB:81:BD:07:62:37:16:CA:95
>
> and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>
> SHA1: 34:BF:77:B0:49:FF:BB:6F:FA:29:49:90:F4:70:0A:94:74:45:15:A8

how to fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: How are you signing your application?  Are you just building and uploading the APK file?  If so, you are probably using the debug key that is automatically generated by the Android tools.  You need to either (a) build/sign the APK in the same environment as you did for the last upload, or (b) Upload it as a new application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the original APK you uploaded is signed with the same certificate. Else you have to upload the file as a new package (new app).

Comment: My computer just reinstalled. so the last solution is i must to create a new application (new package) in google play?

Comment: @Diego-I am getting the same error. So I want to know that is alias name Case Sensitive..??

Answer (score 2):

****The Apk Must be Signed with the Same old Certificate,
 But Now u Are signing With New Certification****

Answer (score 0):

The apk must be signed with the same old certificate, if you have a backup of it, try to sign the apk withe old one. If you don't have old certificate then there's no way.

Comment: @nOiAd-I am getting the same error. So I want to know that is alias name Case Sensitive..??